# How to add watermark to Powerpoint in notes section/Outline view?

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, office-2013

I am trying to add watermark to Powerpoint 2013. I am able to apply text watermark by adding a 'text box' in the *slide master*. But when I go to print preview and change '*Print Layout*' to '*Notes Pages*', there is no watermark in the  notes section.
Also there is no watermark when I change '*Print Layout*' to '*Outline*'.
Is there anyway to apply watermark to notes section and outline view as well ?

Or is it even possible to apply watermark in these scenarios ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the handout (outline) and notes pages masters to add the desired watermarks.

They can be accessed via the "View" menu.

Comment: Is there a way to add the text watermark here. I can add the background color but couldn't find a way to add Text watermark here.

Answer (score 1):

I've Found a way of adding text watermark on notes and outline view. For adding text watermark in Notes Pages, I opened View-> Master Views-> Notes Master-> Format-> Drag and drop Text Box.

Thanks.